# Sharepoint online Flow how to create a sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I would like to dynamically create a list using Flow in SharePoint online.
I don't see that there is an option to create a new list only new item or new file.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It seems the Flow can't provide a option to create a new list currently.

As a workaround, we can create a workflow and create list using REST API.

Reference: [How To Create A List Using HTTP Web Service In SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks.
what i ended up doing is using an azure function and set that as a custom connector that would then appear as an action in flow
i used this:
https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-call-sharepoint-from-microsoft-flow-with-a-help-of-an-azure-function-a5740794341

and then changed the logic to crearte a list instead of a folder